# If value is unavailable then get last month's value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, window-functions

My table produce a monthly data and one column (location) show 0 when data is unavailable or did not register.

What i'm trying to do here is that if the location return 0 for this month, then look for the location one month before.

```
| MONTH    | ID     | LOCATION  |
| Jan 2020 | 1111   | 0         |
| Jan 2020 | 1242   | 23        |
| Jan 2020 | 1425   | 58        |
```

`ID: 1111` should show `Dec 2019`'s location instead `Jan 2020`.

Here where i got so far and when i run the query it doesn't show any result:

```
SELECT c.MONTH, c.ID, CASE WHEN c.LOCATION = 0 then b.LOCATION else c.LOCATION END as LOCATION
FROM DB.TABLE1 c, DB.TABLE1 b
where c.ID = b.ID
and c.MONTH in ('Jan 2020')
and b.MONTH in ('Dec 2019')
```

Any help? 
Thanks

Comment: What if there be more than one Dec 2019 value?  Which one do we take?

Comment: Are you really storing dates as strings, or you actually have a column of `date` datatype?

Comment: There are a lot of months starting from 2015 to Apr 2020. We take 1 month before Jan 2020

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `lag()` with conditional logic. Also, you *should* be storing your dates as `date` datatype rather than strings... so this assumes you do:

```
select
    month,
    id,
    case when location = 0 
        then lag(location) over(order by month) 
        else location
    end as location
from table1
order by month
```

If there may be more than one month in a row with a `0` value, and you want to go back to the first available month with a non-`0` value, then you can use hand clause `ignore nulls`:

```
select
    month,
    id,
    case when location = 0 
        then lag(nullif(location, 0) ignore nulls) over(order by month) 
        else location
    end as location
from table1
order by month
```

Finally: if you really are storing dates as strings, then here is an option that turns them to `date`s before proceeding:

```
select
    month,
    id,
    case when location = 0 
        then lag(nullif(location, 0) ignore nulls) over(order by to_date(month, 'mon yyyy')) 
        else location
    end as location
from table1
order by to_date(month, 'mon yyyy')
```

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have the privileges to change the datatype to date. is there a way to work around strings?

Comment: @user2803287: yes, see the last query in my answer.